# Is there a way for SharePoint 2010 to measure keyword density of PowerPoint files in a library?

Tags: 2010, keyword

I am creating an archive of reports (PowerPoint files) and I am trying to find out if there is a way for SharePoint to scan each document, count how many times each word is used throughout the document and give me the results.

The purpose is to try and categorize the reports, then look for any trends in the amount of reports for each category over time.

I am new to SharePoint so I'm not sure of its capabilities. I know it scans the contents of documents uploaded because they are searchable.

Thanks in advance for any help!